# Profile registeration interaction between wordpress and civicrm

Tags: profile, registration

I have been trying to get my head around using Civicrm (5.13.1) with wordpress (5.2) to create membership options for our organisation. I'm not sure I understand the process of creating a user account though that is synchronised between wordpress and civicrm. 
I managed to set up the membership types, payment processor and sucesfully tested that. I tried setting up some plug ins like CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync, Members and Profile Builder but not sure how to set things up. Ideally we would like to set up a member's only forum eventually, but for now we would like users to be able to log in and edit information like adresses, cancel autorenewals and etc...

Is there a tutorial or resource somewhere that shows one how to set up user log in details for wordpress that can be 'registered' as part of a member signing up to a civicrm membership?

Sorry for the vague question, I'm just a bit lost for directions here.
thank you so much for the help,
best regards,
David

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is in the documentation at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/online-membership-sign-up/ in the Civicrm user guide. It would be best to read the whole membership documentation before and after the link given.
For Wordpress you will need a login system like the one you mention "Profile Builder" which I use myself and can recommend.  You will need to switch on wordpress/settings/General/Membership/Anyone can register but also first get a good security system plug-in otherwise you'll more than likely get a mass of brute-force attempts to infiltrate your system.
You may want to consider a plugin to prevent non-members from seeing certain membership pages.  Alternatively, after you've set up a membership profile, you could use civicrm to forcibly get non-registered users to open a WordPress user account by using the registration option in ...civicrm/administer/customize data/profiles/settings/advanced settings.
There's a lot to be considered.  Hope this helps you to get going.

Comment: If you use the CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync plugin then you do not need to allow the "Anyone can register" option which save a lot of worry about spurious account creation.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. If I use Profile Builder for example, is signing up then a 2 stage process for members? They create their Profile first, then I direct them to the link for the membership/contribution page? Or is there a way to have both happen at once? Is the brute force and spurious account creation a problem if there is no free 'memberships'? 
Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a 2 stage process.  After creating your membership profile to be used in your contribution page, in that profile advanced settings, there is a WP user account registration option where you can make registration required, or as an option (not required), or a no account creation option.  You'll probably want to take the first option I've described to make registration a requirement.  There's an extension called "CiviCRM WordPress Profile Sync" that can be used to keep a WordPress User profile in sync with CiviCRM Contact info.  I haven't used the Member extension.